# Python Tuple of Tuple to Dict

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, tuples

I need to nicely change a tuple of tuples which looks this way

```
 a = ((10,1),(10,2),(10,3),(20,21),(30,31),(30,32),(40,41))
```

to a dict

```
 b = {10:[1,2,3], 20:[21], 30:[31,32], 40:[41]}
```

The source tuple is the result of an SQL Query ; tuple is sorted according first value of each tuple ; each tuple is a couple.

I don't succeed in coding it a pythonic way ? Can someone help ?

Comment: A defaultdict(list) sounds right for this job.

Comment: Use `itertools.groupby` for this: `b = {k: [e[1] for e in g] for k, g in groupby(a, key=operator.itemgetter(0))}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `defaultdict` here from the collections module:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

b = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in a:
    b[k].append(v)

defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {10: [1, 2, 3], 20: [21], 30: [31, 32], 40: [41]})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = list(((10,1),(10,2),(10,3),(20,21),(30,31),(30,32),(40,41)) )

b = {} 
for x, y in a: 
    if x in b: 
        b[x].append(y) 
    else: 
        b[x] = [y] 

# Printing Output 
print(b)
```